# Associating a type of the folder with a cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing an app that requires a folder to be opened with it.

I'd like to see if a folder can be dragged onto the app icon (in the dock, for instance) and the app to recognise it as a valid type to open. How can I associate in xcode the folder type to my app, via the list of UTIs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the folder to be otherwise accessible to the user?   Or are you looking to use this as a Bundle (special folder in OS X that looks like a single "file", but is actually a directory)>

Comment: I do want the folder to be used otherwise. Anyway, I found the solution -- see below.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution in the form of:

(a) editing the Info.plist file with an UTI entry for public.folder,

(b) overriding the function application:openFile: in my implementation of NSApplicationDelegate.

All works now.